# how to create a replicable, unique code for a pre-ISBN book

Tags: isbn, sku

I am putting my collection of some 13000 books in a mySQL database. Most of the copies I possess
can be identified uniquely by ISBN.  I need to use this distinguishing code as a foreign key into
another database table.

However, quite a few of my books date from pre-ISBN ages.  So for these, I am trying to devise a
scheme to uniquely assign a code, sort of like an SKU.

The code would be strictly for private use.  It should have the important property that, when I
obtain a pre-ISBN publication, I could build the code from inspecting the work, and based on the
result search the database to see if I already have other copies in my possession.

Many years ago I think I saw a search scheme for some university(?) catalogue, where you could
perform a search of a title based on a concatenated string' (or code) that was made up of let's
say 8 letters from the title, and 4 from the author, and maybe some other data. For example,
to search 'The Nature of Space and Time' by Stephen Hawking and Roger Penrose you might perform
a search on the string 'Nature SHawk', being comprised of 8 characters from the title (omitting
non-filing words and stopwords) and 4 from the author(s).

I haven't been able to find any information on such scheme's, or whether or not such an approach
was standardized in any way.

Something along these lines could be made up of course, but I was wondering if people here have
heard of such schemes, of have ideas on how to come to a solution to this.
So keep in mind the important property of 'replicability': using the scheme, inspection of a pre-
ISBN dated work should --omitting very special or exclusive cases-- in general lead to a code
that can singly be used to subsequently determine if such a copy is already in the database.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If it doesn't need to be human readable, would a hash of various bits of info do it? Author, title, publication date,etc?

Comment: For what it's worth: _The Nature of Space and Time_ is listed on Wikidata under https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q7753287, which gives a WorldCat record at http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/467756125. The Library of Congress has (an edition) at https://lccn.loc.gov/95035582. Libraries are a thing, and if it's worth it, you might like to consult with one.

Comment: @ivanivan: I was thinking along those lines myself, with some 'protocol' to follow in case of e.g. missing year.

Comment: @Josh Lee: Thanks but I have plenty of info on that (sample) title.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Title (add Author and Publisher as options) and a *series id* to produce a fake isbn. Take a look at [fake_isbn](https://github.com/xlcnd/isbnlib/blob/dev/isbnlib/dev/_helpers.py).

NOTE: use the first digit as a *series id* but don't use 9!